# Passing id in url but json showing the whole array instead of the specific json object linked to the id (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on this ionic project where I retrieve data from json. I have this tab view called News where I list a news title and an image (coming from json), then when you click on an article you go to the details page where you get more info.

The problem that I am struggling with is that I can pass the id in my url but the data in my console is from the whole array, not from the specific json article.

I believe that I didn't make any mistakes in my code (not 100% sure of course). If anybody could point in the right direction and let me know what I perhaps am doing wrong.

[image]

Here is my html code for the details page:

```
<div ng-init="init()">

  <ion-view view-title="Nieuws detail">
    <ion-content class="has-header">

    <p>{{ news_details.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ news_details.content }}</p>
    <p>{{ news_details.description }}</p>

    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>

</div>
```

Here is my service code:

```
.service('ChemicarNewsService', function($http, $q){

    var url1 = "xxxxx";
    var url2 = "xxxxx";

    var self = {
        'newsById' : [],
        'loadNewsFeeds' : function(){
            return $http.get(url1);
        },
        'getNewsById' : function(id){
            return $http.get(url2 + id);
        }
    };
    return self;
});
```

My controller code for the details page:

```
.controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, ChemicarNewsService){

    $scope.init = function(){
        ChemicarNewsService.getNewsById($stateParams.id).then(function(response){
            $scope.news_details = response.data;
            console.log($scope.news_details);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Why are you resolving API call in the state and then injecting the same service and performing the same API call in the service? You can just inject "news"... And for resolving your issue, we need to see the json responses. Plunker would be perfect...

Comment: @JanisP: for the json respons check the screenshot. ok i adjusted my code and deleted the the api call in my state

Comment: I'd start testing your http end point and look through what API you are performing and what is being returned.

Comment: can you confirm it is definitely hitting url2 as xxxxxxx/503, perhaps console it out in case they are joined together.

Comment: No the urls are correct 100% sure